# How to fix "Required" annotation not working in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Here's my movie model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18, 2)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z""'\s-]*$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

But when I test it on my local, these two fields: `Title` and `Genre` don't seem to have the validation that I was expecting, see screenshot below:

[image]

Here's my controller form of actions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using RazorPagesMovie.Models;

namespace RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies
{
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RazorPagesMovie.Models.RazorPagesMovieContext _context;

        public CreateModel(RazorPagesMovie.Models.RazorPagesMovieContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Page();
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            _context.Movie.Add(Movie);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Create.cshtml:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Movie</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Movie.Price" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Movie.Price" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Here's my folder structure: [image]

At first I thought there might be a sequence of validation, but actually after I filled out `Release Date` and `Price`, I was able to create a movie even without filling in `Title` and `Genre`. So apparently the validation for these two fields didn't work.

Could anyone share any insight please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share with us the steps you performed to arrive at this stage in validation. Please show us the code for your view and controller actions.

Comment: Just edited my post with Create.cshtml.cs page. Anything else you need?

Comment: Just for test could you assign *[Required(ErrorMessage="test")]*-attribute and check again?

Comment: I just did that and nothing changed. @vladimir, here's what I did: 
`[StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "test")]
    public string Title { get; set; } `is that what you intended?

Comment: The custom error message did not display. Have you included the JavaScript resources?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more? where am I supposed to include JS resources? I read the doc, it says `A significant benefit is that no code changes were necessary in the Create or Edit pages. Once DataAnnotations were applied to the model, the validation UI was enabled.`

Comment: Could you provide the markup of page (chtml-file) or part where form is defined?

Comment: And in the sentence just before that "The errors are enforced both client-side (using JavaScript and jQuery) and server-side (when a user has JavaScript disabled)."

Comment: I just uploaded a screenshot of my project, which file are you pointing to? @vladimir

Comment: true, which file do you think should be worth inspecting? I just uploaded a screenshot of my project? thanks! @Jasen

Comment: @FisherCoder I mean file *Create.chtml*.

Comment: sure, just added it in my OP. @vladimir

Comment: Thanks, it looks fine. Could you send the html-markup that rendered in browser after click on Create-button?

Comment: Which file is that? I'm still learning .NET, not super familiar yet. :)

Comment: Add Data type for Title and Genre

Answer (score 0):

your required field is never null it is empty string and you must prevent your field from being passed by empty strings like this :

```
[StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false)]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

For required field validation decorate your function with `[BindRequired(ErrorMessage = "Title Required")]` instead of using `[Required(ErrorMessage="Title Required")]`